# How to get javascript key path in long json files in Linux

Tags: json, javascript

I'm using several keys from a long javascript object, represented as json. Example:

```
...
"stock": {
  "type": 'str',
  "properties": {
    "warehouse": {
      "type": 123
    },
    "retail": {
      "type": false
    }
  }
}
...
```

I would like to know the full path of, for instance, the key `type`.  Something like `get-paht type` obtaining `root.somethingElse.stock.properties.retail.type` without having to do it manually.  This is a long file, and searching up and down doesn't seem productive...

Cli or Gui tools tools are fine. However I can't find any application, extension or command-line tool that returns that.

I tried "JsonView" for Chrome but I couldn't make it load a local file.

[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) Also doesn't seem to solve this, since there are some missing double quotes.

**EDIT:** I realized this was a js object, although represented as json.

Comment: [Repair](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4162642) it to proper JSON first, then use `jq`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura: I just edited the question. I hadn't realize this is a js object.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a *correctly formed* and complete MWE :

```
{
  "stock": {
    "type": "str",
    "properties": {
      "warehouse": {
        "type": 123
      },
      "retail": {
        "type": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then using `jq` (v1.5):

```
$ jq -M -c 'path(..|.type? // empty) | join(".")' mwe.json
"stock.type"
"stock.properties.warehouse.type"
```

(add `-r` to omit quoting on output, `-M` and `-c` are for formatting output only). This recurses down the structure (`..`) looking for an index or key of "type", suppresses errors (`?`) when that's not appropriate, and evaluating as "empty" (`//`) when the value is false or null, then flattens (`join()`) the path array.

A possible problem is that a `false` value (or null) triggers `empty` (at least in v1.5, but not in v1.4) and the `stock.properties.retail.type` item is omitted.

Without the `| join(".")` you will get JSON arrays, which may also be useful:

```
["stock","type"]
["stock","properties","warehouse","type"]
```

A more complex version, including the values:

```
$ jq -M -c '[paths(.|select(type=="object" and has("type")) )][] \
            as $path | [$path+["type"], getpath($path + ["type"])]' mwe.json  
[["stock","type"],"str"]
[["stock","properties","warehouse","type"],123]
[["stock","properties","retail","type"],false]
```

This is a little more elegant, it creates an array by selecting all of the objects which have a "type" child, then prints the path to "type" and its value.